# Swagger codegen generating spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am new to swagger codegen with spring boot application.I generated spring boot project using maven openapi-generator-maven-plugin .

If I use swagger editor to generate there are two options one server stub and another one client . What is the purpose of these two?

After generating project, I create a controller class to call the api, is it enough ? or I need to generate client also?

Don't say I did't do proper research. Last two days I am googling with this topic, still no clear idea.

Comment: What is your objective? Generating a spring boot application? Or want to use swagger codegen

Comment: Want to generate spring boot REST project using swagger json file.

Comment: Firstly, your spring boot project wants to call another project which is swagger enabled, means which exposed its endpoints using swagger. For example, you are trying to create a doctor service(spring boot project) which internally invokes other swagger enabled project, for instance say, ( practo API/ service). Now you use maven spring codegen plugin, to generate clients (all API required request classes) without creating manually. By using swagger Json of practo service in your doctor service, you can generate clients to call practo service.

Comment: For more understanding watch this once, [Video on codegen maven](https://youtu.be/QQaFKGU8oi4)

Comment: Thanks Dinesh for quick response. I already created spring boot project using codegen plugin . Now my doubt is , it is enough or I need to generate separate server stub and client ? To learn I create server stub and client from my swagger file using swagger editor and understand that both are more or less same.  Now doubt is for RESP API, generating project using code gen plug in is enough ?

Comment: You cannot create a spring boot project with this maven codegen plug-in. To create a spring boot project, in best way go to start.spring.io
You can only create stubs for an interacting swagger project

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. If interacting with another service, clients are enough, until you have access to them. I mean, until you are authorised to call the endpoints of swagger enabled application, as in my example, practo service. For example, if you are not authorised, but if still want to continue with your integration with practo service, in that case, you can generate a server stub. It generate the stubs(dummy methods) for an API, once you got access, you change redirect to actual practo service API. You can locally deploy this generated server stub & test it.